# Questions regarding drawing in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing, drawrect, cgcontext

I want to create a little navigation bar on the bottom of my iPhone screen where I basically just draw 5 rectangles next to each other. However, only the active page should have the opacity of 1.0 and others should be slightly transparent (alpha=0.4). **That is what I already have.**

**Now my questions:**

- How do I change the opacity of the individual elements of my navigation ? Do I have to redraw the whole thing whenever something changes ? So I would have global variables called nav1Opacity,nav2Opacity...nav5Opacity, change them when the navigation changes and redraw the whole thing ? If so,
- How do I clear what I have drawn before ? Do i create the rectangles as `CGMutablePathRef()`s and store them in an array and clear them all ?

I have very little experience with drawing, so I am a little lost there. I have read the documentation of Quartz2d and contexts, but still, as I mentioned I have not fully figured out how it works.

**Here is some code I use:**

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //save state
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    //NAV1
    CGMutablePathRef nav1 = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(nav1, NULL, CGRectMake(0 , 15, 64, 10));
    UIColor *blueColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x35BFE5,0.1);
    CGColorRef bC = [blueColor CGColor];
    [colorArray addObject:(__bridge id)bC];
    [navArray addObject:(__bridge id)nav1];
    CGPathRelease(nav1);
    /*
     *
     *
     ... I do this for all 5 navigation elements

     *
     *
     */

    //then I go through all my rectangles and add/fill them
    for(int i=0;i<[navArray count];i++){
        CGContextAddPath(context, (__bridge CGMutablePathRef)[navArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (__bridge CGColorRef)[colorArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        CGContextFillPath(context);

    }

    // restore to last saved context state 
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

//and this is how I redraw
-(void)updateActiveNav{
    [navArray removeAllObjects];
    [colorArray removeAllObjects];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: You're basically at the bottom of the barrel before OpenGL kicks in. So there is a lot of boilerplate kind of stuff that has to be done when you do your own drawing. You do in fact have to redraw with the new opacity yourself and handle clearing it out as well. Basically when the active element changes, mark your custom view as dirty with `setNeedsDisplay:` and in your drawrect check for the active one while drawing.

Comment: Could you have a look at the code I provided earlier ? It still always  draws on top of the old navigation, so basically erasing what I have drawn before does not work at all...

Comment: By default calling drawRect should clear what was drawn the last time your called drawRect unless you're redrawing the original yourself. I don't see anything in your shown code that would stop that from happening.

Comment: Ok, I think I solved the problem. But I do not understand why the method above does not work. My solution was simply adding `CGContextClearRect( context , [self bounds]);` to my drawRect to clear the last drawn "objects". But as far as I understand, drawRect redraws my whole view, so if I save the context before drawing, the navigation items should be "overridden" the next time drawRect is called, right ?

Comment: I do use a CGAffineTransform on the view. Does that somehow mess up the frame ? So could I effectively clear the bounds and not the frame somehow ?

Comment: Yes they should as far as I understand as well. Quartz doesn't have a canvas to draw on so everytime its called your should get a new one. The fact that it persists is very strange and probably related to some other code.

Comment: CGAffineTransform shouldn't mess anything up because you're saving and restoring your context. So it knows its transformed while its drawing.

Comment: Strange indeed. There aren't many places I could have messed it up, so I am kind of stuck here...

Comment: Think I figured it out. Try the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually *draw* the interface, you will have to redraw it whenever it changes, at least the rectangles that change. You can reuse CGPaths, but they aren't graphical objects on screen, they are just instructions on how to draw shapes, so you will have to draw everything again.

That being said, you can use individual UIViews instead, which represent onscreen objects, and you can change their opacity, which will reflect on screen.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you. However I'd like to know why my code behaves faulty.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
for(int i=0;i<[navArray count];i++){
        CGContextAddPath(context, (__bridge CGMutablePathRef)[navArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (__bridge CGColorRef)[colorArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        CGContextFillPath(context);

    }
```

You are added the path to your context, then setting a fill color, then filling it. Then without restoring your context you're doing it again so your filling the previous path and the new one. Its not the drawing from the last drawRect its the drawing from here. Try something like below so that after you fill the path you reset the context and draw the next block by itself instead of both the 1st and 2nd etc.

```
for(int i=0;i<[navArray count];i++){
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    // Add Path, Fill
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: I accidentally upvoted the answer, unfortunately it did not help me.

Comment: I copied your code into a project. set up a simple tap gesture to call your redraw and it is clearing fine. You're corrupting your context somewhere else I believe.

Comment: Here is the code. I made a simple copy of your code, added a random number for y and redraw on screen taps. It bounces around because it isn't saving the previous drawing. If it were saving the previous draw it obviously would eventually have multiples. Either something else besides copied drawing is happening or you're corrupting the context somewhere else in your code. http://cl.ly/LXZJ